# reading 'appVerificationDisabledForTesting'

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, recaptcha, one-time-password

i am using latest version of firebase for OTP configuration, as a junior developer i am still learning and follow the instructions as per docs, how ever i am getting the error when i submit for the recaptcha, The error is 'react-dom.development.js:4312 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'appVerificationDisabledForTesting')
i have tried multiple strategies but couldn't resolve this. It is the first time i am setting up the OTP for the app.

````
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";



const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "",
  authDomain: "",
  projectId: "",
  storageBucket: "",
  messagingSenderId: "",
  appId: "",
  measurementId: ""
};


const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const auth = getAuth(app)


import React, { useState } from 'react';
import OTPInput from 'react-otp-input';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { auth } from '../firebase.config';


import {  RecaptchaVerifier } from "firebase/auth";
import toast, { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
const Otp = () => {
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState('');
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const [showOTP, setShowOTP] = useState(false);
  const handleOtpChange = (otp) => {
    setOtp(otp);
  };

  const renderInput = (inputProps) => (
    <input {...inputProps} style={{ width: '3rem', height: '3rem' }} />
  );
  const { phoneNumber } = useParams();
  const submittedData = useLocation().state.submittedData;

  console.log(submittedData)

  function onCaptchaVerify() {
    if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
      window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
        "recaptcha-container",
        {
          size: "invisible",
          callback: (response) => {
            onSignup();
          },
          "expired-callback": () => {},
        },
        auth
      );
    }
  }
  function onSignUp(){
    onCaptchaVerify()
    const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier
    signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, phoneNumber, appVerifier)
    .then((confirmationResult) => {
      // SMS sent. Prompt user to type the code from the message, then sign the
      // user in with confirmationResult.confirm(code).
      window.confirmationResult = confirmationResult;
      setShowOTP(true);
      toast.success("OTP sent sucessfully!")
      // ...
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log(error)
    });
  }
  return (
    <div>

  <Toaster toastOptions={{duration:4000}} />
      <h1>OTP VALIDATION</h1>

      <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>

      <p>Phone Number: {phoneNumber}</p>
      <OTPInput
        value={otp}
        onChange={handleOtpChange}
        numInputs={6}
        separator={<span>-</span>}
        renderInput={renderInput}
        shouldAutoFocus
      />

      <button onClick={onSignUp}>Validate</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Otp;```
````

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `auth` to the `RecaptchaVerifier` function, like this:

```
  function onCaptchaVerify() {
    if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
      window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(
        auth,
        "recaptcha-container",
        {
          size: "invisible",
          callback: (response) => {
            onSignup();
          },
          "expired-callback": () => {},
        }
      );
    }
  }
```

[it's in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth?hl=en&authuser=0#use-invisible-recaptcha)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This is the correct answer. However in the documentation, auth comes last instead of first which leads to the error.